# what's the right type for viper

Tags: go

I have the following yaml file and want to iterate over the cameraids.---

```
--- 
profiles:
  HDready: ' -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 23 -s 1280x720 '
  mobile: ' -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 23 -s 480x270 '

cameraids:
  111:
    fps: 30
  191:
    fps: 50
  851:
    fps: 50
```

I want now to iterate over the cameraids and profiles therefore I declare the variable for cameraids like this

`var camids map[string]interface{}`

The same as the `fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(viper.Get("cameraids")))` prints but I always get the following error `no new variables on left side of :=` when I try to get the map from viper

`camids := viper.GetStringMap("cameraids")`

Please can you explain and help me what I misunderstand, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've declared `camids`

```
var camids map[string]interface{}
```

above, you don't need to use `:=` since the variable `camids` has been already declared.
So just write:

```
camids = viper.GetStringMap("cameraids")
```

---

`:=` is used when you want to declare the variable and assigns the value to it at the same time.

`=` is used when you've already declared the variable beforehand and you're just assigning the value to it.

Comment: Thanks but now I get `video-convert.go:12:6: camids declared and not used` you can see the full code in this snipplet https://gitlab.com/aleks001/visit-at/snippets/1684621

Comment: Go does not allow you to declare variables and then not use them. Are you using the `camids` variable at all? _I can not open the link you've provided_

Comment: @Aleksandar the gitlab link is not working (404). Post snippet to https://play.golang.com or https://gist.github.com. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the gitlab issue. here the gist for the conf and the play for the app. Conf: https://gist.github.com/git001/285162deb0f89ed49ef14c89aaa396fe . APP: https://play.golang.com/p/X93HI2D5Hu

Comment: @Aleksandar as I've already told you. You've declared and initialized the `camids` variable but you're **not using it in your code at all.** This is not allowed in go. If you declare a variable you **MUST** use it or the program wont compile.

Comment: Still when I remove the comment I get the same error https://play.golang.com/p/fDBqUGO1L4

Comment: @Aleksandar why did you remove the comment?

Comment: Because I want to define the var and then use it with viper. Is this the wrong way? I'm going crazy with this stuff. Should I define a var and then use it or what's the right way?

Comment: You've completely misunderstood me on the **usage** part. I hope this [playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/Mkc93m4MSO) will clear up this misunderstanding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159099/discussion-between-aleksandar-and-mihailo).